# how to fix the "The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'" error while getting data from snapshot?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i have this function

```
UserData _userDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return UserData(
      uid: uid,
      userName: snapshot.data()['userName'],
      userEmail: snapshot.data['userEmail'],
      phoneNumber: snapshot.data['phoneNb']
    );
  }
```

but im getting error on the paranthesis

```
The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
```

### updateee for the question

also i have the function and instance of collection

```
final CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

 // get user doc stream
  Stream<UserData> get userData {
    return users.doc(uid).snapshots()
      .map(_userDataFromSnapshot);
  }
```

when i read data:

```
Widget profile(context, user){
    return StreamBuilder<UserData>(
      stream: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).userData,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          UserData userData = snapshot.data;
          print(userData.userName);
         } else print('no data');
      }
     );
}
```

what can i do?

im using versions:

Flutter 2.0.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision c5a4b4029c (1 year, 1 month ago) • 2021-03-04 09:47:48 -0800
Engine • revision 40441def69
Tools • Dart 2.12.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are approaching to the data in two different ways. One of them (which is the first one) is correct but the other ways are wrong. Once you have the document snapshot, get the data out of it and use it as an assigning mechanism.

You can try the code below.

For more information --> https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/

```
UserData _userDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot document) {
    final data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return UserData(
      uid: uid,
      userName: data['userName'],
      userEmail: data['userEmail'],
      phoneNumber: data['phoneNb']
    );
  }
```

Comment: i updated my question for more infoo, i tried ur answer the error disappear but the result is no data

Comment: can you add an else-if and check if there is error. You can do it by `snapshot.hasError`

Comment: i print the error ```snapshot errortype 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'```

Comment: problem solved, the phone number is int in the user model :)